# How to perform the kolmogorov-Smirnov test to test against a Gamma function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I have an array of points and I would like to check if they follow a Gamma distribution with a=15.5 and b=7. I am trying

`scipy.stats.kstest(myarray, gamma.pdf(15.5, 0.143))`

What is the syntax for the `kstest` command? The documentation only shows the basic example with the normal distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Gamma distribution, pass the string `'gamma'` as the second argument, and use the `args` argument to set the shape parameter, the location, and the scale.

Here's an example.  First, I need some data to work with:

```
In [46]: from scipy.stats import gamma, kstest

In [47]: np.random.seed(123)

In [48]: sample = gamma.rvs(a=15.5, loc=0, scale=1./7, size=100)
```

Apply the test with the Gamma distribution with shape 15.5, location 0 and scale 1/7.  Because `args` gives *positional* arguments, we have to include the location:

```
In [49]: kstest(sample, 'gamma', args=(15.5, 0, 1./7))
Out[49]: KstestResult(statistic=0.058075855762720785, pvalue=0.88868922608343937)
```

If we try different scales, we see that the p-value goes down:

```
In [50]: kstest(sample, 'gamma', args=(15.5, 0, 0.16))
Out[50]: KstestResult(statistic=0.18210965421938488, pvalue=0.002249786773449225)

In [51]: kstest(sample, 'gamma', args=(15.5, 0, 0.175))
Out[51]: KstestResult(statistic=0.29663539668929456, pvalue=2.6970075950316641e-08)
```

Comment: How do you get the syntax highlighting of the ipython line numbers? Is SO automatically parsing the plain text that way?

Comment: @PureW Those code blocks are indented four spaces.  You can indent the code yourself, or select the code and use the `{}` button to indent it.  After that, SO takes care of the highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

```
from scipy import stats
stats.kstest(myarray, 'gamma', (15.5, 7))
```